# Nearly ready: Batch-Script to save filenames from each subfolder without extension and save the filenames in a txt in each subfolder

Tags: batch-file, filenames

```
@echo off
chcp 1252
for /r %%a in (*) do echo %%~na >> D:\filenames.txt
echo. >> D:\filenames.txt
```

This script saves all filenames of all subfolder in one txt located in `d:\filenames.txt`. What I need: The script needs to read out the filenames of a subfolder and save a txt in this subfolder. And this for every subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
chcp 1252
for /r /d %%D in (.) do (
  pushd "%%D"
  (for %%F in (*) do echo %%~nF) >filenames.txt
  echo(>>filenames.txt
  popd
)
```

NOTE: Your use of `%%~n` drops the file extension from the list. I suspect you want to trim the drive and path info but include both the file name and the extension. In your original code you would want to use `%%~nxa`. In this solution you could simply use `%%F`, since the value will not include path info. But there is an even simpler way:

To include both name and extension, I would use the following:

```
@echo off
chcp 1252
for /r /d %%D in (.) do (dir /b /a-d "%%D"&echo() >"%%D\filenames.txt"
```

Comment: Well, your first code puts a filenames.txt in every subfolder but the content of the txt is not right. In the subfolders I have mp3-files, one nfo-file. But in the txt is only the filname of the nfo. No mp3-filenames. BTW: I need it withOUT extension. Thanks anyway. I hope we can get it right.

Comment: @JohnSmith - I tested the code, and it works - all files in a given folder are listed. The parentheses must be exactly as written - the entire inner FOR statement must be enclosed by parentheses.

Comment: Ah, so stupid. I looked into the wrong  filenames.txt - the script works fine. But I need the filnames without extension.

Comment: @JohnSmith - My original script gives the names without extension. Change the inner FOR loop file mask to `(*.mp3)` if you only want the mp3 files. Ignore everything after the NOTE: since you truly only want the base name without extension.